# How should I link to static wxWidgets libraries when using gcc / mingw?

Tags: mingw, wxwidgets, static-linking

It's rather frustrating and the most common answer is "do what CodeBlocks does". I don't care. I want to undertand.

The problem is: wxWidgets, when built non-monolithically, is split across several static libraries. Those have to be linked in exactly the right order based on their dependencies, or the static linking will fail.

The libraries are (their file names are abbreviated, but I use their full names for simplicity):

```
wxAdvanced
wxAui
wxBase
wxCore
wxGL
wxHTML
wxMedia
wxNet
wxPropertyGrid
wxQA
wxRibbon
wxRichText
wxSTC
wxWebView
wxXML
wxXRC
```

What is the magic order, where can we look it up - and most importantly: how is it imputed into my project's `CMakeLists.txt`?

Some representative error messages are shown below - perhaps they'll make this Q&A easier to discover via web searches:

```
C:/wxwidgets-install_3.1.3_9/lib/gcc_x64_lib/wxmsw31ud_aui.a(floatpane.cpp.obj):floatpane.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN11wxMiniFrame12ms_classInfoE[.refptr._ZN11wxMiniFrame12ms_classInfoE]+0x0): undefined reference to `wxMiniFrame::ms_classInfo'

C:/wxwidgets-install_3.1.3_9/lib/gcc_x64_lib/wxmsw31ud_core.a(window.cpp.obj):window.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.wxEVT_POWER_RESUME[.refptr.wxEVT_POWER_RESUME]+0x0): undefined reference to `wxEVT_POWER_RESUME'

src/CMakeFiles/wxmaxima.dir/Unity/unity_10.cxx.obj: In function `XmlInspector::XmlInspector(wxWindow*, int)':
C:/projects/wxMaxima/src/XmlInspector.cpp:42: undefined reference to `wxRichTextCtrl::wxRichTextCtrl(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)'
```

Answer (score 6):

The idea, in short is: follow the dependency diagram below, and ensure that the pointed-to libraries (the dependecies) come *after* their dependents (the pointed-from libraries). Ok, *after* you say, but where exactly does this "after" apply? It applies in:

1. the linker/compiler command line with entries like `-lwxbase31ud -lwxbase31ud_net` etc.
2. the `CMakeLists.txt` line that finds wxWidgets, like `find_package(wxWidgets ... base net ...)`

In the latter case, one could of course ask why oh why doesn't CMake's `FindwxWidgets.cmake` module order the libraries correctly, like, I don't know, any other sane CMake framework support module does (Qt, for one)? Well, it's half-broken, and this is just one aspect of it. As a user, you should never have to know about those dependencies when using CMake, and it's not in fact a normal thing to need to worry about since most other major CMake modules handle it (as they should!).

So, in the answer below, anything that has to do with CMake should be considered a workaround to the broken support module. But since such things can take ages to figure out even if you're intimately familiar with the tools involved, it's absurd to expect someone without lots of experience and/or dogged determination to just know this. I hope this answer will save someone some grief :)

#### Dependency Graph for wxWidgets 3.x

[image: the wxWidgets library dependency tree]

When dealing with makefiles yourself, you'll have to maintain this ordering as parameters passed to the linker that puts the exectable together.

When using cmake, the link order follows the `find_package` order.

#### Example

Suppose we have

```
find_package(wxWidgets 3 REQUIRED core base adv xml html aui net richtext)
```

Let's check: `core` comes before `base` - OK, since `core` points-to `base` on the diagram.

But then there are **errors galore**: `adv` must be before `core`. `xml` before `base`, `html` before `core`, `aui` before `adv`, `net` before `base`, and `richtext` before `adv`, `html` and `xml`.

We do a bit of topological sorting and come up with:

```
find_package(wxWidgets 3 REQUIRED richtext aui adv html core xml net base)
```

And indeed: this allows the project to link. Yay!

#### DependencyGraph for wxWidgets 2.5-2.8

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer but I'd just like to add that this information is present in the [manual](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.3/page_libs.html).

Comment: @VZ Oh, I know, that's where the pretty picture comes from, and if you clicked on it, it would have sent you to the manual :) But you see, otherwise that manual page is useless. Because yeah, it's cool that it shows a cool graphic, but it doesn't explain whatsoever what to do with that information. If you search for posts of people who had such problems, it's obvious that the manual page's marketing dept did a terrible SEO job, because 1) nobody finds it as a solution to their problem, and 2) it doesn't tell you what to do (as in: reorder like so, in this line of CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: @VZ In general, cmake's manual is a permanent record of lack of technical communication skills. It's absolutely awful. It provides no rationale for almost anything, it just presents facts and it's up to you to make any use of those facts. And the various books on this topic don't improve anything (lest someone tell me the typical excuse "you need to read a book about it"). I have every single book published about cmake, They sit in a stack in the basement, and 50% of their contents are an insult to intelligence of the reader. They don't answer any hard questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the picture was a link. As for the rest, there are many, many ways to build wxWidgets applications. Recently CMake seems to be really establishing itself as the de facto standard (unfortunately), but there are still plenty of people using MSVS solutions, Xcode projects or just manual makefiles too. We can't really document all possible use cases, so we just give the dependencies from which the correct library order can be deduced.